# How to set an IMG on the top right corner of a Bootstrap card?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to set an image on the top right corner on a bootstrap card (overlaying the card). I positioned the image with position absolute. And I think that's the problem. If I change the screen size the image is on the old position but the card moved. How can I fix the image on the corner even if I change the screen size?

the result should look like this:
[image: **enter image description here**]

Thank you!

```css
#hat {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 420px;
  top: -25px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid mt-2">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mt-md-5">
      <div id="santabox">
        <img id="hat" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="hat">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-header text-center">
            <h3>
              Text
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to move absolute image `#hat` by left attribute with absolute value `420px`. If you would like to place it to right corner, you have to use `left: 100%` or `right: 0`. Also you want `#santabox`
 to be relative.

---

#### Solution

I've set `top` and `right` attributes of `#hat` on `0` - which means I've placed it in the top-right corner. After that, I've applied `transform: translate(50%,-50%);` to move it by 50% of its own size (center it to the top-right corner) and I've made `#santabox` relative by setting `position-relative` class.

```css
#hat {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid mt-2">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mt-md-5">
      <div id="santabox" class="position-relative">
        <img id="hat" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="hat">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-header text-center">
            <h3>
              Text
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```css
#hat {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
```

```html
 
 <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mt-md-5">
      <div id="santabox">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-header text-center" style="padding: 0px;">
            <img id="hat" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="hat">
            <h3 style="padding: 14px;">
              Text
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```